# logrotate custom "rotate" action equivalent for upstart?

Tags: upstart, logrotate, rsyslog, sysvinit

In lots of online posts regarding how to rotate your `iptables` log files, for example [here](http://blog.shadypixel.com/log-iptables-messages-to-a-separate-file-with-rsyslog/) `rsyslog` config files get reloaded by the `postrotate` option of `logrotate`, presumably in order to stop `rsyslog` from writing to the old (now compressed or renamed logfile) and to the new logfile. Usually this looks like

```
 postrotate
            invoke-rc.d rsyslog rotate > /dev/null
 endscript
```

I believe this is now outdated, since `rsyslog` has been converted to `upstart`, and is no longer `Sys V Init` so something along the lines of

```
service rsyslog reload > /dev/null
```

is probably the way to go.

But what about the "rotate" action? (I think it was a `logrotate` custom action...somehow set via `policy-rc.d` perhaps..). I presume for `Sys V Init` this was somehow superior to a simple reload/restart (although I don't know exactly why), is it possible or desired in the new `upstart` framework to get `logrotate` use a "rotate" action to restart `rsyslog` rather than just doing a reload?

Answer (score 0):

Upstart is an init system, not a log rotater. Use a simple shell script (not an init script though) to rotate the logs.